# Does the speaker have to be a representative?

Tags: united-states, us-house-of-reps

Is there a requirement that the speaker needs to be a representative, or could they elect anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. They do not have to be a member of the House. They **do** have to be elected/appointed by the Majority of the House-elects, however. It’s an unspoken rule that they be a member of the House, but not one written in the Constitution, which is all that matters.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).